# Remove XML namespace attributes from MVC Web API response

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am getting the following response from an MVC Web Api;

```
<Products xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="my.namespace.com">
<Product>
<Id>1</Id>
<Name>Tomato Soup</Name>
<Category>Groceries</Category>
<Price>1</Price>
</Product>
<Product>
<Id>2</Id>
<Name>Yo-yo</Name>
<Category>Toys</Category>
<Price>3.75</Price>
</Product>
<Product>
<Id>3</Id>
<Name>Hammer</Name>
<Category>Hardware</Category>
<Price>16.99</Price>
</Product>
</Products>
```

I would like to remove the xmlns:* tags.

I have found various posts, including some on SO that give options, but these do not appear to work.

What I have tried;

```
[XmlRoot("Products",Namespace = "my.namespace.com")]
    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public class ProductsModel : List<Product>
    {
    }

[XmlRoot("Product")]
    [DataContract(Namespace = "", Name = "Product")]
    public class Product 
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Category { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

These have no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `DataContract`, use `CollectionDataContract`, without enabling the `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: Close. Updating the CollectionDataContract and disabling serializer removes the xmlns:xsd tag, but not the xmlns:xsi Tag. I have updated the question with that code as well.

Comment: Why do you want to remove this attribute? Your XML is a schema instance, is it not?

Comment: Have you read this? http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization You may need to use the XmlSerializer. From the page: "The XmlSerializer class supports a narrower set of types than DataContractSerializer, but gives more control over the resulting XML. Consider using XmlSerializer if you need to match an existing XML schema."

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, I have not been able to get anything to change.

Comment: Please provide an example. :)